# Android Studio add maven based project lib as depedencies

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I use Android Studio to develop android app, it seems using gradle to manage depedencies,

Now i want to add [StickyScrollViewItems](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems) ProjectLib as dependency, and it seems using maven, as i am not see .gradle configuration file there

Here the directory structure of my project (and what i want)

- [+] build
- [o] build.gradle
- [-] MyMainProject

  - [+] bin
  - [+] build
  - [o] build.gradle
  - [o] MyMainProject.MyMainProject.iml
  - [o] pom.xml
  - [-] src

    - [+] main
    - [+] test
- [+] gradle
- [o] gradlew
- [o] local.properties
- [o] pom.xml
- [-] project-module         <- i put the module here

  - [-] StickyScrollviewItems         <- this is the module project root

    - [-] library          <- it seems the main lib is here

      - [o] AndroidManifest.xml
      - [-] gen

        - [-] com

          - [-] emilsjolander

            - [-] StickyScrollViewItems

              - [o] BuildConfig.java
              - [o] Manifest.java
              - [o] R.java
      - [o] library.iml
      - [o] pom.xml
      - [o] proguard-project.txt
      - [o] project.properties
      - [-] src

        - [-] com

          - [-] emilsjolander

            - [-] StickyScrollViewItems

              - [o] StickyScrollViewItems.java
    - [+] out
    - [+] sample       <- ths module project working sample app
    - [o] pom.xml
    - [o] Readme.txt
- [o] settings.gradle
- [+] src

Legend:
[+] Closed Directory
[-] Opened Directory
[o] File

How i can do this, so i can call

`import com.emilsjolander.SticlyScrollViewItems.R;`

like the sample does, (please refer to the working example in StickyScrollViewItems)

BTW, my android studio version is 0.3.1, and assume my main package containing main script is com.mycompany.mymainproject

---

Okay, i successfully convert the maven dependencies into gradle using

```
gradle --setupbuild pom
```

here the generated gradle file:

**settings.gradle** in root of StickyScrollViewItems

```
rootProject.name = 'parent'
include ':library', ':sample'
project(':library').projectDir = "$rootDir/library" as File
project(':sample').projectDir = "$rootDir/sample" as File
```

**build.gradle** in root of StickyScrollViewItems

```
allprojects  {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    group = 'com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  sourceCompatibility = 1.6
  targetCompatibility = 1.6
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
  }
}
```

**build.gradle** inside of library

```
description = 'StickyScrollViewItems - Library'

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.google.android', name: 'android', version:'4.0.1.2') {
       /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
       This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
       Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */
    }
}
```

now help me what should i write in settings.gradle, and build.gradle in my prject root and MainProject folder

tell me if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your MyMainProject's build.gradle file

```
dependencies {


compile project(':StickyScrollviewItems')
```

}

hope this should be work

Comment: First Thanks for your reply, Here what i get after i sync the gradle: Failed to refresh Gradle project 'MyMainProject': Project with path ':StickyScrollviewItems' could not be found in project ': MyMainProject'. Build file '/Users/username/Documents/eclipse_workspace/MyMainProject/MyMainProject/build.gradle' line: 33

Comment: please add this in setting.gradle file include ':StickyScrollviewItems'

Comment: Thanks, i already done including StickyScrollviewItems, to myproject (maybe), but i still can't resolve com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViews.R;